# How can I write a git alias that takes a string as an argument

Tags: git, zsh, git-alias, git-grep

I would like to write a git alias for:

```
git log --all --grep='Big boi'
```

What I have so far is:

```
[alias]
    search = "!f() { str=${@}; echo $str; git log --all --grep=$str; }; f"
```

Which echos the string perfectly fine but gives an error, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the string to the grep flag.

```
$ user in ~/src/repo on master λ git search 'Big boi'
Big boi
fatal: ambiguous argument 'boi': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I'm using zsh if it makes any difference . . .

Comment: Git alias processing aside, your function should be `f() { str="$*"; echo "$str"; git log --all --grep="$str"; }`. There is no call for using `$@` here, because you aren't trying to treat the expansion as a sequence of separate words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That alias seems to work if you are using double-quotes:

```
git search "Big boi"
```

I also made it work with `--grep=\"$str\"` (and still using double-quotes)

The [OP joshuatvernon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3912417/joshuatvernon) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040686/how-can-i-write-a-git-alias-that-takes-a-string-as-an-argument/49043250?noredirect=1#comment85129419_49043250):

> I amended it to

```
search = "!f() { str="$*"; echo "$str"; git log --all --grep=\"$str\"; }; f"
```

> and it works with single, double or no quotes.

Comment: The alias should be fixed; the user shouldn't have to know what type of quotes to use to satisfy Git's alias rules.

Comment: With a mixture this @VonC answer and the comment by @chepner I amended it to `search = "!f() { str="$*"; echo "$str"; git log --all --grep=\"$str\"; }; f"` and it works with single, double or no quotes

Comment: @joshuatvernon Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.